# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dask'

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, pip

I already install task through !pip install dask. But Jupiter still show me error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dask' ".

I already try !pip3 install task  !pip3 install --user --upgrade dask and other

Comment: When you install a Python package using pip, sometimes,  it might not be installed in the same environment that your Jupyter notebook is running in

Comment: and how to fix this?
never happened to me before

Answer (score 0):

In the notebook, issue the command `!pip freeze`. That will list all modules installed.
Look down the list of modules. Check the list for missing modules. If they are not there then the following may help

If on Windows, issue the command.
`!where python`

if on Linux I think the command is `!which python`.
That will list all the paths to python.exe

In another cell perform the following.

```
import sys
sys.path
```

Use all the information to locate where the python.exe file that is supporting the notebook is located. The pip commands must be applied to that python.exe.